# Ansible using common user and pass to hosts

Tags: ansible

I've a hosts file with 4 host ip's and I'm always using "ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user=user ansible_ssh_pass=pass" besides host ip to verify the connection.

But, this is difficult to add these many times. Could someone please tell me where can I keep common these parameters and pass it to all my host ip's at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Create file in directory all in directory group_vars with the content.

```
ansible_connection:ssh
ansible_ssh_user:user
ansible_ssh_pass:pass
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Imma !

Comment: I've created a section in my host file instead of creating separate folder structure but it's throwing some error. Here is my actual code format I'm using 

Content of the file my_hosts ....

[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_ssh_user=user
ansible_ssh_pass=pass

IP1
IP2

I'm trying to execute using this command ....

ansible -m ping -i my_hosts all

Comment: Here's the error I'm getting on the console....

ERROR! Attempted to read "my_hosts" as YAML: Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/*********/my_hosts': line 1, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


[all:vars]
    ^ here

Attempted to read "my_hosts" as ini file: my_hosts:6: Expected key=value, got: IP1

Comment: Thank you so much Imma !

It's working perfectly .... created a file all under group_vars with below content and executed by my regular command


ansible_connection:ssh
ansible_ssh_user:user
ansible_ssh_pass:pass